# coreutils; Where is the `pipe` program?

Tags: pipe, gnu-coreutils

Given a program `A`; I'm writing a script, which runs the following command;

```
echo "Text-To-Be-Processed" | A | cat
```

`A` is non-essential for functionality, but eases usability. I have a check in place to determine if `A` is available; If this isn't the case, I'd like to replace `A` with a no-op program (i.e. the `pipe` program (`|`)).

Such that my command becomes;

```
echo "Text-To-Be-Processed" | pipe | cat
```

I could simply branch upon whether `A` is available, but this leaves me with duplicate code (of the rest of the command). I've considered using named pipes, but it all seems like unnecessary workarounds.

My current solution is `./pipe.sh`; `if read -t 0; then cat; else echo "$*"; fi`, which enables the drop-in solution, but *feels* wrong somehow.

*NOTE: Replacing `A` with the `|` command as;*

```
echo "Text-To-Be-Processed" | | | cat
```

*Doesn't work either.*

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps tee to /dev/null. As in:

```
echo "Text-To-Be-Processed" | tee /dev/null | cat
```

Comment: I just realized a major shortcoming of my original post; namely that I pass arguments to `A`, which needs to be ignored by the `pipe`.
Most programs reject with an error alike; `invalid option`.